# Work around std::showbase not prefixing zeros

Tags: c++, c++11, std

Couldn't find help online. Is there any way to work around this issue?

`std::showbase` only adds a prefix (for example, `0x` in case of `std::hex`) for non-zero numbers (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273654/ostream-showbase-non-present-for-zero-value-and-internal-doesnt-work-for-handl/32220055#32220055)). I want an output formatted with `0x0`, instead of `0`.

However, just using: `std::cout << std::hex << "0x" << ....` is not an option, because the right hand side arguments might not always be integers (or equivalents). I am looking for a showbase replacement, which will prefix 0 with `0x` and not distort non-ints (or equivalents), like so:

```
using namespace std;

/* Desired result: */
cout << showbase << hex << "here is 20 in hex: " << 20 << endl; // here is 20 in hex: 0x14

/* Undesired result: */
cout << hex << "0x" << "here is 20 in hex: " << 20 << endl;     // 0xhere is 20 in hex: 20

/* Undesired result: */
cout << showbase << hex << "here is 0 in hex: " << 0 << endl;   // here is 0 in hex: 0
```

thanks a lot.

Comment: It really is a bit odd. Even though you use a `hex` prefix, the `0` is still printed in *octal*.  :-)  [Is 0 a decimal literal or an octal literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895522/is-0-a-decimal-literal-or-an-octal-literal)

Comment: i'm not sure i understood you question, but it's a const int& ... the fact that it is not printed as a `hex`, is just the definition of `std::showbase` as explained in the link that i put in the OP

Comment: It was an insider joke about the fact that, accordning to the grammar, `0` is an octal number. And you get that even when you explicitly ask for it in hex.

Comment: This would seem to be a bug? If you explicitly set the base to 16 (`std::hex`) then `std::showbase` would be expected to comply. You just identified a problem that was dragging me down the rabbit hole.

Comment: oh, and printf trips people up too... https://stackoverflow.com/a/14733899/9220132

Answer (score 2):

try

```
std::cout << "here is 20 in hex: " << "0x" << std::noshowbase << std::hex << 20 << std::endl;
```

This way number will be prefixed with `0x` always, but you will have to add `<< "0x"` before every number printed.

You can even try to create your own stream manipulator

```
struct HexWithZeroTag { } hexwithzero;
inline ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const HexWithZeroTag&)
{
  return out << "0x" << std::noshowbase << std::hex;
}

// usage:
cout << hexwithzero << 20;
```

To keep setting between `operator<<` call, use answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/799877/1630041) to extend your own stream. You would have to change locale's `do_put` like this:

```
const std::ios_base::fmtflags reqFlags = (std::ios_base::showbase | std::ios_base::hex);

iter_type 
do_put(iter_type s, ios_base& f, char_type fill, long v) const {
     if (v == 0 && ((f.flags() & reqFlags) == reqFlags)) {
        *(s++) = '0';
        *(s++) = 'x';
    }
    return num_put<char>::do_put(s, f, fill, v);
}
```

Complete working solution: http://ideone.com/VGclTi